# MySQL Transpose data into columns but with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Order     Property           Value
-----     --------           -----
  1       person1_tel        555-1234
  1       person1_address    123 Road
  1       person2_tel        555-4321
  1       person2_address    321 Ave
  1       shipping_tel       555-5555
  1       shipping_address   468 Place
```

I would like to get it to look like this:

```
Order    Type      Telephone    Address
-----    ----      ---------    -------
  1      person1   555-1234     123 Road
  1      person2   555-4321     321 Ave
  1      shipping  555-5555     468 Place
```

There is a lot more than just 2 types of properties but this is just to give an idea. I know how to pivot the table but I'm not sure how to properly group them by type since the type itself isn't a column.

I would also like to know, if there is a solution, would it be faster to parse it in PHP instead?

Comment: Well, this is what you get for not [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema... if you *must* do it, you can `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Property, '_', 1) AS Type ... GROUP BY Order, Type`—but it will be horrifically slow and unmanageable as your database grows in size.

Comment: Yes, the schema was not created by me, nor can it be altered. I was asked to write a script for it. Since posting, I decided I would be better off just outputting them in separate tables and parsing them in PHP. Way faster and less complicated, it just sucks that it has to be in 5 or 6 different queries.

Comment: "Nor can it be altered" -- Is your resume up to date?

Comment: I'm not in charge of the database, I have no access nor can I convince them to restructure their whole system. So do you have anything of value to add or do you want to continue to be a pretentious troll?